# Prevent Azure function from recursive execution

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have created an Azure function that is triggered by an EventGrid subscription event which is fired when a new blob uploaded into Blob Storage.

I'm using this function to resize the uploaded image, it's uploading the resized image into the **same** container

The problem is that the function will trigger new upload event which is done from inside the function itself, so it will execute again. the original image and also the resized image should be stored in the same container, so I can't prevent this just bu filtering the Event Subscription based on the container name.

EventGrid Subscription has a part for advanced filtering, in this section we can filter the event based on the `data` object in the payload, that would be a good idea but I can't find a way to put any custom field in `data` object when uploading resized image from azure function, so that I can filter events based on that.

[image]

function implementation:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const Jimp = require('jimp');

const {
  Aborter,
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
} = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
const uploadOptions = { bufferSize: 4 * ONE_MEGABYTE, maxBuffers: 20 };

// const containerName = process.env.BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME;
const accountName = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
const accessKey = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
  accountName,
  accessKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

module.exports = async (context, event, inputBlob) => {  
  context.log(`Function started`);
  context.log(`event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const widthInPixels = 100;
  const blobUrl = context.bindingData.data.url;
  const blobUrlArray = blobUrl.split("/");
  const blobFileName = blobUrlArray[blobUrlArray.length - 1];
  const blobExt = blobFileName.slice(blobFileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  const blobName = blobFileName.slice(0, blobFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
  const blobName_thumb = `${blobName}_t.${blobExt}`;

  const containerName = blobUrlArray[blobUrlArray.length - 2];

  const image = await Jimp.read(inputBlob);
  const thumbnail = image.resize(widthInPixels, Jimp.AUTO);
  const thumbnailBuffer = await thumbnail.getBufferAsync(Jimp.AUTO);
  const readStream = stream.PassThrough();
  readStream.end(thumbnailBuffer);

  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName_thumb);
  context.log(`blockBlobClient created`);
  try {
      await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(readStream,
            uploadOptions.bufferSize,
            uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
            { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image/jpeg" } });
      context.log(`File uploaded`);
  } catch (err) {

    context.log(err.message);

  } finally {

    context.done();

  }
};
```

Bindings:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "eventGridTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "dataType": "binary"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a very basic issue when using Azure functions for triggering blob storage events, and it's really weird that I can't find a proper description in this regard, inside the big azure documentation!

Comment: Why don't you just put the resized images in a seperate container?

Comment: *I have created an Azure function which triggers an EventGrid subscription event which fires when a new blob uploaded into Blob Storage.*

Are you sure you don't mean *I have created an Azure function that **is triggered** by an EventGrid subscription event which **is fired** when a new blob is uploaded into Blob Storage.*? Otherwise I am not really sure what your function exactly does.

Comment: @PeterBons, Thank you for correction, I want it to be in the same container, that's not the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EventGrid Subscription has a part for advanced filtering, in this section we can filter the event based on the data object in the payload, that would be a good idea but I can't find a way to put any custom field in data object when uploading resized image from azure function, so that I can filter events based on that.

Correct, you can't put anything in the data object as you have no control over the creation of the event. This is of course due to the fact that the event is generated by the Azure Platform. You can only create filters based on the content of the event, which is ([according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event)):

```json
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/test-container/blobs/new-file.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 524288,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/new-file.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

That leaves you with 2 choiches. Either use a staging container in which files are uploaded and have the function resize them and put them in the final container or create a mechanism preventing from newly created thumbnails from being processed.

Maybe in your function you can inspect the name of the blob, and if it is a thumbnail them just end processing.

Or, my preferred solution, include [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata-javascript) in the thumbnail blobs when you create and store them. Then, also in the function, upon execution, check for the existance of the metadata and only if no metadata is set, execute the resize logic.

Comment: Peter, there is also another choice in this solution, such as an advanced filtering on the subject to eliminate files with '__t.' contents in the blobName_thumb, see the code line: _const blobName_thumb = `${blobName}_t.${blobExt}`;_

Comment: Yes, I'll use metadata approach, the issue with it is that the function will get called twice per each upload, but there is no other proper option

Comment: @RomanKiss I don't have control over the name of the original image, so it would be a bit risky as the original image's name can be something like `img_t.jpg`

Comment: @PeterBons one of the good solutions is that EventGrid subscription can be filtered by the Access Key, I mean for example if the request came with a specific Access Key, then fire the event, otherwise ignore, or filter it if it has this specific Access Key, let azure team know about it, if you have access to them! :)

Comment: @M.mhr in the case of know a file extension, you can use the _StringNotEndsWith_ for instance: _t.jpg _t.png _t.jpeg  ....

Comment: @RomanKiss you're right about being able to filter by name in the subscription. If that is doable for M.mhr that would be the better solution

Comment: @PeterBons another way how to filter it is to use a **data.clientRequestId** property on the well-known value of the header **x-ms-client-request-id** populated in the subscriber, see the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#event-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use an optional property *clientRequestId* of the data object in the event message for advanced filtering, see this property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#event-properties).
Based on that description, the upload client in your subscriber should populate a client header **x-ms-client-request-id** with a well-known value used for advanced filtering purpose, for instance in my test, I am using the value *ABCD-1234*

The following screen snippet shows an example (simulation of the upload client) of the event message, when the blob has been created using the REST API PUT request, where the header *x-ms-client-request-id* has been setup with a value *ABCD-1234*

[image]

As you can see the above picture, the **clientRequestId** has this well-known value, so the advanced filtering for subscription can be configured with the following:

[image]

Based on the above solution, such as a **clientRequestId** used by upload client in the subscriber we can prevent to invoke this subscriber again.

Answer (score -1):

When you upload the resized images, please set metadata as per the below document and filter that in that event subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata

[image]

Comment: Apart from the screenshot, how does this differ from the answer already given? To my knowledge you can't filter on metadata in the actual subscription, only in the code, but I happily stand corrected.

Comment: Do I have access to MetaData in EventGrid Subscription? can you please provide an example?. I can set metadata for the new blob in the function, but I don't have access to metadata in the event subscription. I can also filter based on Data in the event subscription but can't change Data inside the function!

Comment: @M.mhr you don't have access to the metadata in the susbcription. You only have access to that in the code of your function. The event grid event schema makes that clear.

Comment: @PeterBons Right, thats why I'm asking